# Do I need to run devenv.exe /setup twice? [VS 2005 and 2008]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-addins

I am writing a VS Integration Package and setup using Visual Studio Setup Package. I have a custom action that runs "devenv.exe /setup" when the package is installed.

If the user has VS 2005 and 2008 installed, do I need to run devenv.exe /setup from both directories? Like so:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /setup"

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /setup"

Or will running just one be sufficient? If so, which one should I run? (2008 I presume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to run both.  They are two independent environments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which one you are installing to.  VSIP packages install into a version of Visual Studio vs. a machine.  So you should only have to run devenv /setup on the version of Visual Studio to which your package installs.  Running devenv /setup on the version you did not install to will have no effect.

Comment: Good point.  Also, if you have written a package for VS2003, then running setup for either 2005 or 2008 will have no effect either ;)